Why do my PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy manifests in Pods disappear when I reinstall my Pods?
For my iOS app, I performed a directory search on the Pods directory and found several PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy files that had been added by the pod install process.
As a control test, I deleted my Pods directory and reinstalled all files.
Now the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy files have disappeared. They no longer exist in the Pods directory?
Where did they go?
